# JavaScript Regex - check for enum value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Currently I have a text field that allow user to enter an `Enum` value. Once they enter a value I need to validate those value first and throw an error message if not match.

The `Enum` format will be -

```
yes|no|maybe#yes
yes | no | maybe #yes
1|2|3|4|5#0
```

1. string must have `|` symbol, so in the future I able to split the characters.
2. `#` symbol and the end. This will be a "default value" for enum.

How to create this regex? Thanks in advance.

Comment: first off what have you tried? please show us. Second, you say that `#` at the end is the default value, but you write `#0` but I don't see that it has option `0`

Comment: believe me I have try a lot, but none of it match with my string.that's y i come here. `#0` I just made up those number. I just thinking worst case scenario, what happen if user enter 0 value or null. Means they do not want a default value.

Comment: **_believe me I have try a lot_** -> how can we until you show some efforts to us @dontbannedmeagain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that "yes|no|maybe#yes" and "yes | no | maybe #yes" are *the same*, in that the whitespace before or after the divisors don't attribute.

You can extract all the values you require using regex, `/\s*[|#]\s*/`

For example:

```js
// ["5","6","7","7"]
console.log("5 | 6 | 7 # 7".split(/\s*[|#]\s*/));
```